# How to create a frequency list of every word in a file?

Tags: bash, file-io, sed, grep

I have a file like this:

```
This is a file with many words.
Some of the words appear more than once.
Some of the words only appear one time.
```

I would like to generate a two-column list. The first column shows what words appear, the second column shows how often they appear, for example:

```
this@1
is@1
a@1
file@1
with@1
many@1
words3
some@2
of@2
the@2
only@1
appear@2
more@1
than@1
one@1
once@1
time@1
```

- To make this work simpler, prior to processing the list, I will remove all punctuation, and change all text to lowercase letters.
- Unless there is a simple solution around it, `words` and `word` can count as two separate words.

So far, I have this:

```
sed -i "s/ /\n/g" ./file1.txt # put all words on a new line
while read line
do
     count="$(grep -c $line file1.txt)"
     echo $line"@"$count >> file2.txt # add word and frequency to file
done < ./file1.txt
sort -u -d # remove duplicate lines
```

For some reason, this is only showing "0" after each word.

How can I generate a list of every word that appears in a file, along with frequency information?

Comment: You could use a hash-table to create a histogram, or maybe use a Trie.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Not `sed` and `grep`, but `tr`, `sort`, `uniq`, and `awk`:

```
% (tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2"@"$1}') <<EOF
This is a file with many words.
Some of the words appear more than once.
Some of the words only appear one time.
EOF

a@1
appear@2
file@1
is@1
many@1
more@1
of@2
once.@1
one@1
only@1
Some@2
than@1
the@2
This@1
time.@1
with@1
words@2
words.@1
```

In most cases you also want to remove numbers and punctuation, convert everything to lowercase (otherwise "THE", "The" and "the" are counted separately) and suppress an entry for a zero length word. For ASCII text you can do all these with this modified command:

```
sed -e  's/[^A-Za-z]/ /g' text.txt | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -v '^$'| sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

Comment: This is quite a nice solution.  One thing you may want to do is provide a way of removing trailing periods as well.  perhaps inserting  `| sed -e 's/\.$//g'` between `tr` and `sort` in your pipeline.

Comment: I thought about that, but the original post said punctuation would be removed before this step.

Comment: Well, just a modification to your solution to remove punctuations and capitals, in case they aren't removed. Also, this removes unnecessary whitespace, squeezes extra spaces and prints the words with the highest frequency first: `cat file.txt | tr '[:punct:]' ' ' | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' | tr -s ' ' | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn`

Comment: this is great. any way to make it skip comments? e.g. `# comment`

Answer (score 49):

**uniq -c** already does what you want, just sort the input:

```
echo 'a s d s d a s d s a a d d s a s d d s a' | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq -c
```

output:

```
  6 a
  7 d
  7 s
```

Comment: I would also recommend adding one more `sort -n` at the end of that line to cause your output to be sorted from smallest to largest.

Answer (score 13):

You can use tr for this, just run

```
tr ' ' '\12' <NAME_OF_FILE| sort | uniq -c | sort -nr > result.txt
```

Sample Output for a text file of city names:

```
3026 Toronto
2006 Montréal
1117 Edmonton
1048 Calgary
905 Ottawa
724 Winnipeg
673 Vancouver
495 Brampton
489 Mississauga
482 London
467 Hamilton
```

Comment: awesome! Is this possible to do that for bigrams, trigrams?

Comment: not worked for me with this text: "the day is sunny the the
the sunny is is
". I got result: 3 the
      2 sunny
      2 is
      1 the
      1 is
      1 day   and not: the 4
is 3
sunny 2
day 1

Comment: Worked for me with your sentence. Result: 4 the
   3 is
   2 sunny
   1 day
   1

Answer (score 7):

Content of the input file

```
$ cat inputFile.txt
This is a file with many words.
Some of the words appear more than once.
Some of the words only appear one time.
```

Using `sed | sort | uniq`

```
$ sed 's/\.//g;s/\(.*\)/\L\1/;s/\ /\n/g' inputFile.txt | sort | uniq -c
      1 a
      2 appear
      1 file
      1 is
      1 many
      1 more
      2 of
      1 once
      1 one
      1 only
      2 some
      1 than
      2 the
      1 this
      1 time
      1 with
      3 words
```

`uniq -ic` will count and ignore case, but result list will have `This` instead of `this`.

Comment: Is there a way to group words of the same frequency in a single line? e.g. "2 appear of some the" instead of having them scattered in multiple lines

Answer (score 6):

### Let's use AWK!

This function lists the frequency of each word occurring in the provided file in Descending order:

```sh
function wordfrequency() {
  awk '
     BEGIN { FS="[^a-zA-Z]+" } {
         for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
             word = tolower($i)
             words[word]++
         }
     }
     END {
         for (w in words)
              printf("%3d %s\n", words[w], w)
     } ' | sort -rn
}
```

You can call it on your file like this:

```sh
$ cat your_file.txt | wordfrequency
```

---

*Source: [AWK-ward Ruby](http://tomayko.com/writings/awkward-ruby)*

Comment: one line: `cat file | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i){D[$i]++}}END{for(k in D)print k, D[k]}' | sort -k2nr | head -n 20`

Comment: I love this. I added it to my `zshrc` and use it consistently. Thanks! @Sheharyar

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you:

```
tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' <file |
tr -d '[:punct:]' |
tr -s ' ' '\n' | 
sort |
uniq -c |
sed 's/ *\([0-9]*\) \(.*\)/\2@\1/'
```

Answer (score 3):

If I have the following text in my file.txt.

```
This is line number one
This is Line Number Tow
this is Line Number tow
```

I can find the frequency of each word using the following cmd.

```
 cat file.txt | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq -c
```

output :

```
  3 is
  1 line
  2 Line
  1 number
  2 Number
  1 one
  1 this
  2 This
  1 tow
  1 Tow
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's do it in Python 3!

```
"""Counts the frequency of each word in the given text; words are defined as
entities separated by whitespaces; punctuations and other symbols are ignored;
case-insensitive; input can be passed through stdin or through a file specified
as an argument; prints highest frequency words first"""

# Case-insensitive
# Ignore punctuations `~!@#$%^&*()_-+={}[]\|:;"'<>,.?/

import sys

# Find if input is being given through stdin or from a file
lines = None
if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    lines = sys.stdin
else:
    lines = open(sys.argv[1])

D = {}
for line in lines:
    for word in line.split():
        word = ''.join(list(filter(
            lambda ch: ch not in "`~!@#$%^&*()_-+={}[]\\|:;\"'<>,.?/",
            word)))
        word = word.lower()
        if word in D:
            D[word] += 1
        else:
            D[word] = 1

for word in sorted(D, key=D.get, reverse=True):
    print(word + ' ' + str(D[word]))
```

Let's name this script "frequency.py" and add a line to "~/.bash_aliases":

```
alias freq="python3 /path/to/frequency.py"
```

Now to find the frequency words in your file "content.txt", you do:

```
freq content.txt
```

You can also pipe output to it:

```
cat content.txt | freq
```

And even analyze text from multiple files:

```
cat content.txt story.txt article.txt | freq
```

---

If you are using Python 2, just replace

- `''.join(list(filter(args...)))` with `filter(args...)`
- `python3` with `python`
- `print(whatever)` with `print whatever`

Answer (score 1):

The sort requires GNU AWK (`gawk`). If you have another AWK without `asort()`, this can be easily adjusted and then piped to `sort`.

```
awk '{gsub(/\./, ""); for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {w = tolower($i); count[w]++; words[w] = w}} END {qty = asort(words); for (w = 1; w <= qty; w++) print words[w] "@" count[words[w]]}' inputfile
```

Broken out onto multiple lines:

```
awk '{
    gsub(/\./, ""); 
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        w = tolower($i); 
        count[w]++; 
        words[w] = w
    }
} 
END {
    qty = asort(words); 
    for (w = 1; w <= qty; w++)
        print words[w] "@" count[words[w]]
}' inputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit more complex task. We need to take at least the following into the account:

- removing punctuation; sky is different from sky. or sky?
- Earth is different from earth, god from God, moon from Moon, but The and the are considered the same. So it is questionable whether to lowercase the words or not.
- we must take the BOM character into account

```
$ file the-king-james-bible.txt 
the-king-james-bible.txt: UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text
```

The BOM is the first metacharacter in the file. If not removed, it might incorrectly affect one word.

The following is a solution with AWK.

```
    {  

        if (NR == 1) { 
            sub(/^\xef\xbb\xbf/,"")
        }

        gsub(/[,;!()*:?.]*/, "")
    
        for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
    
            if ($i ~ /^[0-9]/) { 
                continue
            }
    
            w = $i
            words[w]++
        }
    } 
    
    END {
    
        for (idx in words) {
    
            print idx, words[idx]
        }
    }
```

It removes the BOM character and replaces punctuation characters. It does
not lowercase the words. In addition, since the program was used to count the words of the Bible, it skips all verses (the if condition with continue).

`$ awk -f word_freq.awk the-king-james-bible.txt > bible_words.txt`

We run the program and write the output into a file.

```
$ sort -nr -k 2 bible_words.txt | head
the 62103
and 38848
of 34478
to 13400
And 12846
that 12576
in 12331
shall 9760
he 9665
unto 8942
```

With `sort` and `head`, we find the top ten most frequent words in the Bible.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have edited the program.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -Eio "\w+" test.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr

-E: extended regular expression
-i: ignore upper/lower case
-o: only outputs the match pattern

"\w": [a-zA-Z0-9_]
+: repeat the preceding character 1 or more times
sort: sort the word (alphabetic)
uniq -c: count unique words
sort -n: sort by word frequence
```

[image]

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: This is the only option that only select words, other solutions will give incorrect answers if you have stopwords such as `.` and `,`

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A map 
words="$1"

[[ -f $1 ]] || { echo "usage: $(basename $0 wordfile)"; exit 1 ;}

while read line; do 
  for word in $line; do 
    ((map[$word]++))
  done; 
done < <(cat $words )

for key in ${!map[@]}; do 
  echo "the word $key appears ${map[$key]} times"
done|sort -nr -k5
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  awk '{ 
       BEGIN{word[""]=0;}
    {
    for (el =1 ; el <= NF ; ++el) {word[$el]++ }
    }
 END {
 for (i in word) {
        if (i !="") 
           {
              print word[i],i;
           }
                 }
 }' file.txt | sort -nr
```