# Count the frequency of a number in a file with awk

Tags: awk

I have the following file:

```
1
1
2
3
3
3
4
4
5
5
5
5
```

I would like to count how many times a number appear and how many times this is frequent: for example, the number 1 appear 2 times, the number 2 one time, the number 3 three times, the number 4 two times the 5 four times; the output would be a two columns file in which the first column how many times the number appear in the column, the second column represent the times in which a number is repeated, :

```
2 2  %(because the number 1 and number 4 appear 2 times and there are only 2 number that appear this often)
1 3
1 1
1 4
```

I hope that the output example file can help to understand...

Comment: Is it necessary to use `awk` or can you use other unix command?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a frequency list of every word in a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552803/how-to-create-a-frequency-list-of-every-word-in-a-file)

Comment: Yep I would like to do it with a awk script

Comment: I do not understand the `2 1` in you output.

Comment: It was a mystake, I made an edit, sorry :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this line should give you the result:

```
awk '{a[$0]++}END{for(x in a)b[a[x]]++;for(x in b)print b[x], x}' file
```

with your data:

```
kent$  cat file
1
1
2
3
3
3
4
4
5
5
5
5

kent$  awk '{a[$0]++}END{for(x in a)b[a[x]]++;for(x in b)print b[x], x}' file
1 4
1 1
2 2
1 3
```

Answer (score 6):

`uniq` requires sorted input since it compares only consecutive lines:

```
uniq -c
```

So if not already sorted:

```
sort | uniq -c
```

The output for you given example would be:

```
  2 1
  1 2
  3 3
  2 4
  4 5
```

Comment: It does count, but it does not match what the OP wants: `2 2` as `4` and `1` appear twice.

Comment: Agree, it does not do the job.