# Bash - word/term frequency per line (i.e. document)

Tags: regex, bash, text-processing

I have a file `rev.txt` like this:

```
header1,header2
1, some text here
2, some more text here
3, text and more text here
```

I also have a vocabulary document  with all unique words from  `rev.txt`, like so (but sorted):

```
a
word
list
text
here
some
more
and
```

I want to generate a term frequency table for each line in `rev.txt` where it lists the occurence of each vocabulary word in each line of `rev.txt`, like so:

```
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0     
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 
0 0 0 2 1 0 1 1
```

They could be comma separated as well.

This is similar to [a question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552803/how-to-create-a-frequency-list-of-every-word-in-a-file). However, instead of search through the entire document, I want to do this line by line, using the complete vocabulary I already have.

Re: Jean-François Fabre

Actually, I am performing these in MATLAB. However, bash (I believe) would be faster for this preprocessing as I have direct disk access to the files.

Comment: and your first programming language choice was bash to do that ? It means that you know bash, so please show us some code.

Comment: And please tag sensibly. I'm pretty sure `machine-learning` has got nothing to do with this.. You might be working on that domain, but that doesn't mean you've to tag it here.. ;) Also, please have a look at [mcve].

Comment: There are many similar questions to this. If you google "bash word frequency counter" you'll probably find your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Normally, I would use python, but* limiting myself to using **bash**, this **hacky one-liner** solution will works for the given test case.

`perl -pe 's|^.*?,[ ]?(.*)|\1|' rev.txt | sed '1d' | awk -F' ' 'FILENAME=="wordlist.txt" {wc[$1]=0; wl[wllen++]=$1; next}; {for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){wc[$i]++}; for(i=0; i<wllen; i++){print wc[wl[i]]" "; wc[wl[i]]=0; if(i+1==wllen){print "\n"} }}' ORS="" wordlist.txt -`

---

### Explanation/My thinking...

In the first part, `perl -pe 's|^.*?,[ ]?(.*)|\1|' rev.txt`, was used to pull out everything after the first comma (+removing the leading whitespace) from "rev.txt".

In the next part, `sed '1d'`, was used to remove the first i.e. header line.

In the next part, we specified `awk -F' ' ... ORS="" wordlist.txt -` to use whitespace as a field delimiter, the output record delimiter as no space (note: we will print them as we go), and to read input from wordlist.txt (i.e. the "vocabulary document with all unique words from rev.txt") and stdin.

In the awk command, if the FILENAME is equal to "wordlist.txt", then (1) initialize array `wc` where the keys are the vocab words and the count is 0, and (2) initialize a list `wl` where the word order in the same as wordlist.txt.

```
FILENAME=="wordlist.txt" {
  wc[$1]=0;
  wl[wllen++]=$1;
  next
};
```

After initialization, for each word in a line of stdin (i.e. the tidy rev.txt), increment the count of the word in `wc`.

```
{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
    wc[$i]++
    };
```

After the word counts have been added for a line, for each word in the list of words `wl`, print the count of that word with a whitespace and reset the count in `wc` back to 0. If the word is the last in the list, then add a whitespace to the output.

```
  for (i=0; i<wllen; i++) {
    print wc[wl[i]]" ";
    wc[wl[i]]=0;

    if(i+1==wllen){
      print "\n"
      } 
    }
  }
```

Overall, this should produce the specified output.

Comment: you can replace your `perl | sed` with the more lightweight `tail -n+2 | cut -d' ' -f2-`

Comment: @webb Brilliant idea!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one in awk. It reads in the vocabulary file `voc.txt` (it's a piece of cake to produce it automatically in awk), copies the word list for each row of text and counts the word frequencies:

```
$ cat program.awk
BEGIN {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"  # order for copying vocabulary array w
}
NR==FNR {                                 # store the voc.txt to w
    w[$1]=0
    next
}

FNR>1 {                                   # process text files to matrix
    for(i in w)                           # copy voc array
        a[i]=0
    for(i=2; i<=NF; i++)                  # count freqs
        a[$i]++
    for(i in a)                           # output matrix row
        printf "%s%s", a[i], OFS
    print ""
}
```

Run it:

```
$ awk -f program.awk voc.txt rev.txt
0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0
0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0
0 1 1 0 1 0 2 0
```