# add ordinal ranking to word frequency in bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk

Similar to this question [How to create a frequency list of every word in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552803/how-to-create-a-frequency-list-of-every-word-in-a-file)

I want to create a frequency table for words with a different output. Instead of having just the word and its frequency I would like to have the ranking of the word. So that the most frequent word is number 1, 2nd less frequent is 2 and so on. Words with the same frequency should have the same ranking.

I tried to understand the `awk` syntax or the other suggestions but I did not manage.

Example of input text file:

```
ora
remo
ora
ora
hello
tr
tr
tr
remo
rand
rand
rand
hello
```

Output should look like:

```
tr 1
rand 1
ora 1
remo 2
hello 2
```

Comment: If "*words with the same frequency should have the same ranking*", then why is `tr` ranked higher than `rand` and `ora`? Wouldn't they all have the same rank?  Also, what have you tried? I see `bash` and `awk` tags on your question, but I don't see any bash or awk code.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your expected output:

```
sort file|uniq -c|sort -r|awk '$1!=L{L=$1;c=++a}{print $2, c}'
```

Result:

```
tr 1
rand 1
ora 1
remo 2
hello 2
```

---

**Explanation**

First step: **sort** the file as `uniq` expects.

```
$ sort file
hello
hello
ora
ora
ora
rand
rand
rand
remo
remo
tr
tr
tr
```

From `uniq` man page:

> Repeated **lines** in the input will **not be detected if they are not**
>   **adjacent**, so it may be necessary to sort the files first.

Next: Let’s **count** it:

```
$ sort file|uniq -c                                            
   2 hello
   3 ora
   3 rand
   2 remo
   3 tr
```

> `-c` Precede each output line with the count of the number of times the line occurred in the input, followed by a single space.

Third step, **sort** again the file in **reverse** order:

```
$ sort file|uniq -c|sort -r                                    
   3 tr
   3 rand
   3 ora
   2 remo
   2 hello
```

**Finally** the `awk` part:

`awk '$1!=L{L=$1;c=++a}{print$2, c}'`

The idea is simple:

`$1!=L`: Increment the rank `c=++a` **only when the first field** (the one that refers to the count) **changues**. 
Also we're going to use `L` to store `$1` last/previous value

`{print $2, c}`:  [*Applies for all the records*] print the current word (second field) followed by it's ranking.

Answer (score 1):

Kludgy solution ([`datamash`](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/datamash/), `mktemp`, `nl`, *etc.*) until something cleaner comes to mind:

```
x=`mktemp`
datamash  -g 1 -s count 1 < file | 
datamash -s -g 2 reverse | 
tac | tee $x | cut -f1 | uniq | nl | 
while read a b ; do 
    sed -n "/^$b/{s/^$b\W*\(.*\)/\1\t$a/p}" $x ; 
done ; rm $x
```

Output:

```
tr      1
rand    1
ora     1
remo    2
hello   2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **GNU** `awk`, results are same, but order differs a bit

**One-liner:**

```
awk 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"}{a[$1]++}END{for(i in a){ if(a[i]!=p){r++; p=a[i]}print i,r}}' infile
```

**Explanation:**

```
awk '
     BEGIN{
             PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"
          }
          {
             a[$1]++
          }
       END{
           for(i in a)
           { 
              if(a[i]!=p)
              {
                r++; 
                p=a[i]
              }
              print i,r
           }
          }
  ' infile
```

**Ref :**

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Array-Traversal.html

- `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` - In order to control the order in which gawk traverses an array during a for loop.
- `"@val_num_desc"` - values, treated as numbers, are ordered from high to low.
- `a[$1]++` `a` is array, `$1` being array index, and array `a` holds count of occurrence, array key.
- `if(a[i]!=p){r++; p=a[i]}` since array values are sorted in descending order, whenever there  is change in array value, increment `r++`, `p=a[i]` variable holds previous value, used for comparison.

**Input:**

```
$ cat infile
ora
remo
ora
ora
hello
tr
tr
tr
remo
rand
rand
rand
hello
```

**Output:**

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"}{a[$1]++}END{for(i in a){ if(a[i]!=p){r++; p=a[i]}print i,r}}' infile
rand 1
tr 1
ora 1
hello 2
remo 2
```